# P/Invoke throw System.ExecutionEngineException when upgrading .NET (3.5 -> 4.5)

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I am using nsis7z.dll to extract 7z files. The code works just fine on .NET 3.5, but when I compile using .NET 4.5, it does extract the 7z file, but crashes afterwards with a System.ExecutionEngineException exception. From what I've searched it seems like there's something problematic with the parameters sent using the P/Invoke, mostly the one passed as ref.

The code:

```
        public static bool ExtractNsis7z(string i_FileName, string i_ToDirectory)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = GlobalAlloc((uint)GlobalMemoryFlags.GPTR, (UIntPtr)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(stack)));

        stack st = (stack)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(stack));

        st.next = IntPtr.Zero;

        for (int i = 0; i < i_FileName.Length && (i < st.text.Length - 1); i++)
        {
            st.text[i] = i_FileName[i];
        }

        return Extract7z(IntPtr.Zero, 0, i_ToDirectory, ref st, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public class stack
    {
        public IntPtr next;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 260)]
        public char[] text;

    };
    [DllImport("nsis7z.dll", EntryPoint = "Extract", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool Extract7z(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 stringSize, String outputDirectory, ref stack theStack, IntPtr extra);


    enum GlobalMemoryFlags : uint
    {
        GMEM_FIXED = 0x0000,
        GMEM_MOVEABLE = 0x0002,
        GMEM_ZEROINIT = 0x0040,
        GMEM_MODIFY = 0x0080,
        GMEM_VALID_FLAGS = 0x7F72,
        GMEM_INVALID_HANDLE = 0x8000,
        GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_ZEROINIT),
        GPTR = (GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT),
        /*The following values are obsolete, but are provided for compatibility with 16-bit Windows. They are ignored.*/
        GMEM_DDESHARE = 0x2000,
        GMEM_DISCARDABLE = 0x0100,
        GMEM_LOWER = GMEM_NOT_BANKED,
        GMEM_NOCOMPACT = 0x0010,
        GMEM_NODISCARD = 0x0020,
        GMEM_NOT_BANKED = 0x1000,
        GMEM_NOTIFY = 0x4000,
        GMEM_SHARE = 0x2000
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GlobalAlloc(uint uFlags, UIntPtr dwBytes);
```

Comment: `ref Stack` looks wrong, because `Stack` is a class. No idea why you feel the need to call `GlobalAlloc` to get unmanaged memory. Since we cannot see the C++ side of the interface it's hard to say more. I suggest that if you really want help you show equivalent C++ code.

Comment: It is actually correct, a crazy NSIS plugin api convention.  GlobalAlloc is correct as well, at least he doesn't shoot his leg off with an unterminated string.  How the GC heap gets corrupted is pretty hard to see, the very first thing the plugin does is assign *stack* to a global variable.  Very ugly code, it should be removed.  The .NET wrapper for 7-zip is an obvious alternative.

Comment: I'm unable to find the original source of the DLL. All I know is that this code runs perfectly fine on .NET 3.5 and crashes on .NET 4.5

Comment: It's probably broken on 3.5 too and you get lucky. Use the lib that @Hans refers to.